# Unable to configure WiFi Ad-Hoc network in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, adhoc

Was trying to set a WiFi Ad-Hoc in Ubuntu 14.04,
Added the following lines in /etc/network/interface file

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
       address 10.30.11.100
       netmask 255.255.252.0
       wireless-mode Ad-Hoc
       wireless-essid  Ubuntutest
       wireless-key 12345678
       wireless-channel 3
       broadcast 10.30.12.255
       gateway 10.30.10.118 ///My ethernet ip
```

My Ifconfig wlan0 output

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:6d:04:8b:90:0f  
          inet addr:10.30.11.100  Bcast:10.30.12.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0 MB)  TX bytes:0 (0 KB)
```

Im am not getting an Ipv6 id and "Running Multicast is also missing".
So when I remove the ethernet connection, my wifi also becomes unavailable.
What should be done to keep the WiFi ad-hoc intact.